# Cummulative to differential data in MySQL table

Tags: mysql, sql, date

I have a table as

```
+-----------+--------+------------+-------------+
| taxino    | driver | allotdate  | returndate  |
+-----------+--------+------------+-------------+
| 31032     | John   | 2014-06-13 | 2014-06-15  | 
| 31032     | John   | 2014-06-18 | NULL        |
| 40001     | John   | 2014-01-01 | 2014-06-01  |
| 40001     | Alice  | 2014-06-15 | NULL        |
| 40002     | Alice  | 2014-05-17 | 2014-06-18  |
| 40003     | Robin  | 2014-06-17 | 2014-06-18  |
+-----------+--------+------------+-------------+
```

This table shows when a taxi was allotted to driver, NULL in returndate column indicates that the taxi is not returned.
I have a distance-report table as

```
+------------+---------+------------+-----+
|  taxi    | reportdate | distance_in_km  |
+------------+---------+------------+-----+
| 40001   | 2014-04-30 |              527 |
| 40001   | 2014-05-26 |             1497 |
| 40002   | 2014-04-30 |             1414 |
| 40002   | 2014-05-26 |             2796 |
| 40003   | 2014-04-22 |              392 |
| 40003   | 2014-05-26 |             1663 |
+------------+---------+------------+-----+
```

The distance here is cumulative, that is, the distance traveled on previous reportdate is added in the next report. Using these tables I want to know which driver drove the taxi how long, no matter which taxi he drove. As shown below:

`Driver` |  `date` | `distance_traveled_by_driver`.

Here the distance_traveled_by_driver is not cumulative, that is, it contains the distance traveled between two report dates. Please help me doing this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query shows distance driven since the last report date

```
select driver, reportdate, distance_since_last from (
    select t1.driver, 
    t2.reportdate,
    if(@prevTaxi = t2.taxi,
        t2.distance_in_km - @prevDistance,
        t2.distance_in_km) distance_since_last,
    @prevTaxi := t2.taxi,
    @prevDistance := t2.distance_in_km
    from table1 t1
    join table2 t2 on t1.taxino = t2.taxi
    cross join (select @prevDistance := 0, @prevTaxi := 0) t3
    order by taxi, reportdate
) t1
```

Comment: Thanks a lot : getRealName("FuzzyTree");

Comment: But when I do this, I get 5 columns instead of three. It is important becoz I will create a temporary table out of the data generated by this query. So please do something to remove these extra columns.

Comment: @ShailPandey you can wrap the query into a derived table and only select the needed columns, see update